Add Page curl effect to in_app_webview epub reader in flutter
I am showing epub file with the attached code in my application.
I am using javascript to change font styles and settings as you can see in the code. What I want to do is that I want to add a page curl effect to swipe pages back and forth using javascript. What I accomplished till now is that the page curl animation plays but doesn't go to next page or previous page after animation completes and it shows white background instead of the next page under that.
How can I do that??
InAppWebView(
                        onProgressChanged: (s, p) {
                          progress = p / 100;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        onWebViewCreated: (s) {
                          webViewController = s;
                          setState(() {});

                          webViewController?.platform.clearAllCache();
                          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                            webViewController?.platform
                                .clearClientCertPreferences();
                          }
                          styleWebView =
                              StyleWebView(controller: webViewController!);
                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "share",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                final text = (args[0])['text'];
                                if (Utils.token.isEmpty) {
                                  Alerts.dialog(context,
                                      child: const LoginDialog());
                                  return;
                                }
                                Alerts.bottomSheet(context,
                                    child: ShareBottomSheet(
                                      cubit: cubit,
                                      text: text,
                                      id: widget.id,
                                    ));
                              });

                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "translate",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                log(args[0].runtimeType.toString());
                                final text = (args[0])['text'];
                                Alerts.dialog(
                                  context,
                                  child: TranslationDialog(
                                    text: text,
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "current_chapter",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                // log("here current chapter $args");
                                // log("here current chapter ${args[0][0].runtimeType}");
                                // if (args[0].isNotEmpty) {
                                final text = /* args[0].isNotEmpty
                                    ? */
                                    (args[0][0])
                                    /*  : {
                                        "href": "index_split_001.html",
                                        "label": "مقدمة",
                                        "pages": "1",
                                        "cfi": "/6/6[id19]"
                                      } */
                                    ; /* Platform.isIOS
                                    ? (args[0][0])
                                    : args[0].isNotEmpty
                                        ? (args[0][0])
                                        : {"label": "", "href": ""}; */
                                isCurrentBookMark = false;
                                currentChapter = ChapterWebview.fromJson(text);
                                setState(() {});
                                // }
                              });
                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "reader_customization",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                final data = (args[0]);
                                textStyle = textStyle.copyWith(
                                    fontFamily: data['font_family'],
                                    fontSize:
                                        double.tryParse(data['font_size']),
                                    height:
                                        double.tryParse(data['line_height']));
                                textAlign = styleWebView.textAlignFromName(
                                    data['text_alignment'] ?? "center");

                                backgroundColor = Color(int.parse(
                                        data['background'].substring(1, null),
                                        radix: 16) +
                                    0xFF000000);

                                if (data['background'] == "#333333") {
                                  brightness = Brightness.dark;
                                }
                                setState(() {});
                              });

                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "add_note",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                final data = args[0];
                                Alerts.dialog(context,
                                    child: AddNoteDialog(
                                      bookId: widget.id,
                                      chapterName: data["chapter_name"] ?? "",
                                      content: data['text'] ?? "",
                                      path: data['path'] ?? "",
                                    ));
                              });
                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "current_bookmark",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                isCurrentBookMark = true;
                                setState(() {});
                              });
                          // webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                          //     handlerName: "done_saving_location",
                          //     callback: (args) async {});

                          webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "chapters",
                              callback: (args) async {
                                log("here chapters $args");
                                final chapters = (args[0]);
                                chaptersWebView = [];
                                for (var element in chapters) {
                                  chaptersWebView
                                      ?.add(ChapterWebview.fromJson(element));
                                }
                                setState(() {});
                                print(chaptersWebView?.length);
                              });
                        },
                        contextMenu: ContextMenu(
                            onCreateContextMenu: (s) {
                              webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(
                                  source: openMenu);
                            },
                            settings: ContextMenuSettings(
                                hideDefaultSystemContextMenuItems: true)),
                        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: webUri),
                        gestureRecognizers: <Factory<
                            OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                          Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                          ),
                          Factory<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => LongPressGestureRecognizer(),
                          ),
                          Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => TapGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onTap = () {
                                print("tapped");
                              },
                          ),
                          Factory<TapAndHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => TapAndHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onDragStart = (details) {
                                print(details);
                              },
                          ),
                          Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onUpdate = (details) {
                                log(details.delta.toString());
                              },
                          ),
                          Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => PanGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onUpdate = (details) {
                                log(details.delta.toString());
                              },
                          )
                        },
                      ),
    ```

